# Write the first ten terms of the arithmetic sequence given the first term and some other information

Tags: sequences-and-series

The first term of the arithmetic sequence is 24. So,
$$a_1=24$$
The first, fifth and the eleventh term are the consecutive terms of the geometric sequence. So,
$$...,a_1,a_5,a_{11},...=...,b_1r^x,b_1r^{x+1},b_1r^{x+2},...$$

Write the first ten terms of the arithmetic sequence.

---

The solution is

> $$24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51$$ or $$24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24$$

Please explain to me how do we arrive at that solution.

Comment: are both solutions accepted?

Comment: Yes. They are both given as the solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ be the arithmetic  sequence step and let $b$ be the geometric sequence step. Also let $r_i$ be the **arithmetic** sequence's elements.

For the fifth element:

$r_5=r_1+4a$

$r_5=r_1 b$

For the eleventh element:

$r_{11}=r_1+10a$

$r_{11}=r_1 b^2$

Hence:

$r_{1}(b-1)=4a$

$r_{1}(b^2-1)=10a$

In case $b \neq 1$ then

$b=1.5$ and $a=3$

In case $b=1$ then

$b=1$ and $a=0$

Comment: Instead of $b+1=2.5$ it may be better to write $b=1.5$.

Comment: the fith element of the arithmetic sequence equals the second element of the geometric sequence. The eleventh element of the arithmetic equals the third element of the geometric sequence. Given that the first, fifth and the eleventh term are the consecutive terms of the geometric sequence

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand one more thing. How do you infer $r_5(b-1)=4a$?

Comment: My bad i blew up trying to hot fix the base index format.

Comment: Can you fix it?

Comment: I eddited my answer.
r1(b−1)=4a and 
r1(b-1)(b+1)=10a

Comment: I had trouble finding a way to output the eleventh element as a base index. In an attempt to write it properly i miss typed  the indeces of the equation you are reffering to. My eddited answer has the correct indeces and you won't have trouble understanding it. Im sorry for the confusion i might have caused you.

Comment: No problem. It happened to me too a few times.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the GP has a common ratio of $r$.

For the case where $\boxed{r\neq 1}$, the three terms are $24, 24r, 24r^2$.

As these are the first, fifth and eleventh terms of an AP, 
$$\frac {24r^2-24r}{24r-24}=\frac {11-5}{5-1}\\
r=\frac 32 \qquad (r\neq 1)$$
i.e. the GP is $24, 36, 54$.

It can then be easily worked out that the common difference of the AP as $3$.
 Hence the AP is $\color{red}{24, 27, 30, \cdots }$.

For the trivial case where $\boxed{r=1}$, all terms of the GP and AP are equal to $24$.

Comment: How did you go from $(24r^2-24r)/(24r-24)$ to $(11-5)/(5-1)$? I understand that $24=a_1,24r=a_2,24r^2=a_{11}$, but how can you infer that the ratio between $(24r^2-24r)/(24r-24)$ and $(11-5)/(5-1)$ is the same? I see that we can infer $(a_{11}-a_5)/(a_5-a_1)$, but not how we can infer $(11-5)/(5-1)$.

Comment: It can be easily shown that $\frac {T_q-T_p}{T_p-T_m}=\frac {q-p}{p-m}$, where  $T_n=a+(n-1)d$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** $a_{5} =a_{1} +4d$ and $a_{11} =a_{1} +10d$ for some $d$. Also, $a_{5}= r a_{1}$ and $a_{11} =r^{2} a_{1}$ for some $r$. Try to come up with a $2 \times 2$ nonlinear system for $d$ and $r$.